# Batch rename directories in OSX

Tags: macos, batch, rename, batch-rename

I currently have a large set of directories containing photos. The directories are currently named in the format of `yymmdd_text`. I would like to rename them all to `yyyy-mm-dd Text` (notice capitalized `text`).

I have tried making a workflow using `Automator` but the `rename Finder items` function there is quite limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the code below into a text file (like "renameDir.pl").  Then open a Terminal windows where your folders are, and run the script like `renameDir.pl 14*` (or whatever pattern will match the folders you want renamed).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

foreach my $dir (@ARGV) {
  (my $year, my $month, my $day, my $text) = ($dir =~ m/^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)_(.*)/);
  if ($year && $month && $day && $text) {
    my $Text = ucfirst($text);
    my $newDir = "20$year-$month-$day $Text";
    print "Moving \"$dir\" to \"$newDir\"\n";
    move($dir, $newDir) or die "Unable to rename $dir:\n$!\n";
  }
  else {
    warn "Unable to parse $dir\n";
  }
}
```

Assumes that all of your new folder names want to start with a year like 20xx, not 19xx, but you can edit the script to handle that as needed.

Comment: Two questions: This looks like it's creating a new directory and moving the files into it, I just wanted the directories renamed. Am I misunderstanding how this works? Also, I don't know perl but this looks like you missed the capitalization part. Don't you want something like `$Text = capitalize($text)` followed by `my $newDir = "20$year-$month-$day $Text";`?

Comment: You're right about the capitalization. Swap 'my $newDir = "20$year-$month-$day $text";' for 'my $newDir = "20$year-$month-$day " . uc($text);'. This does rename the dir; it doesn't make a new dir and copy the files. Test it out on a copy of one of your dirs. it definitely worked for me.

Comment: And that should be `ucfirst()`, as the edited answer shows, not just `uc()` as my Comment above shows.  That's what I get for answering on my phone and not thinking before I respond.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the cp command to copy and rename your directory for instance?

cp /home/yymmdd_text/* /home/yy-mm-dd_text/

Comment: The whole point is that it needs to be a batch command. The accepted answer above worked great.